# Taskbar Eliminator not reliably removing taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I'm using taskbar eliminator to remove my windows 7 taskbar as I prefer my mix of rainmeter and rocketdock, however it doesn't really work all that reliably.

The taskbar appears when windows starts and I have to manually run taskbar eliminator again to remove it. The taskbar occasionally pops up of its own accord again later regardless.

The program is set to run on startup and while I am using Soluto, Taskbar Eliminator is set to stay in boot. I have two screens and manage them with DisplayFusion

Comment: Have you tried sending their support an email?

Comment: I'll give it a go, but I'm not sure I have enough data for a bug report, was wondering whether anybody had experienced and worked around the problem, or if they knew of a better app to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into similar problems with other start-ups under Windows 7; here's something you can try:

Figure out how it's launching at startup, stop it from doing it that way, and instead create a Windows Task to start it.  When you create the task set the 'trigger' to begin the task "At log on" and then set the trigger 'advanced settings' to delay the task for 30 seconds.

[image: Task Trigger]

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 2):

Install Objectdock and use the "Hide Windows taskbar" option available in the settings, you can make the dock itself "invisible" using the settings properly. I just did this and it fixed this problem at once, easily at that.... I've also been using Taskbar Elim. for a lomg time but it doesn't seem to work properly with Win7, but with this trick you won't be needing it anyway.
I'm real happy.... no more annoying taskbar, YAY!!